# phone auth when user changes device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Am using firebase phone authentication. When user signs in he creates a profile which I save on realtime database . How can the user access the same profile info if he signs out and later signs in again or when they change device but sign in again using the same phone number ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the same user signs in (on the same or on a different device), they'll get the same UID from Firebase. So as long as you store the profile information in the database under their UID, you can access it the same as before.